# transposing a matrix fails

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying to transpose a matrix but it fails at some point. I couldnt find where I make mistake.
First I create a matrix as a jagged array. I init it. swap each items but it remains same. transpoz function changes element partially but at the end of operation it remains same

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<iomanip>
#include<string> 
#include<limits> 
#include<vector>

using namespace std;  

void init_matrix(int** source)
{
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            source[i][j]=count; count++;
        }
    }
}
void matrix_transpoz(int** source)
{
    int temp; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            temp = source[i][j];
            source[i][j] = source[j][i];
            source[j][i] = temp;
            cout << source[i][j] << "\t";
        }cout << endl;
    }cout << endl;
}
void print_matrix(int** source)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            cout << source[i][j] << "\t";
        }cout << endl;
    } 
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    int** arr; 
    int count = 1;
    arr = new int* [5]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[5];
    }

    init_matrix(arr); 
    print_matrix(arr); cout << endl; 
    matrix_transpoz(arr); 
    print_matrix(arr); cout << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you swap twice the same pair of data, at the end, you get the initial matrix. Just use `for (int j = i+1; j < 5; ++j)`

Comment: if I do that it fills half of the matrix.

Comment: I was considering the `matrix_transpoz(.)` function, not the `init_matrix(.)` function. Or I miss something?

Comment: probably you miss something. because for loop runs only once for all elements

Comment: If you swap `[1][2]` then swap `[2]|1]`, final matrix is equal to the input matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I don't understand there are 25 elements in matrix. for loop runs 25 times. it change all element only once. why it equals same thing. what should I do to correct output,

Comment: @dilem-ma-vi It changes "all elements" with *what* ?? Ans: another element in the matrix, which means each element is changed *twice* when you're done. Consider this, you swap [0][0] with [1][1]. Fine. Then later, you swap [1][1] with [0][0]. Now you're back where you started. If its possible to put it an simpler than that, having now been told three times by two different people, I don't see how.

Answer (score 3):

If you swap twice the same pair of data, at the end, you get the initial matrix. Just use

```
for (int j = i+1; j < 5; ++j)`
```

to avoid swapping two times the same data.

**Output:**

```
1   2   3   4   5   
6   7   8   9   10  
11  12  13  14  15  
16  17  18  19  20  
21  22  23  24  25  

1   6   11  16  21  
2   7   12  17  22  
3   8   13  18  23  
4   9   14  19  24  
5   10  15  20  25
```

**Code:**

````
#include<iostream> 
#include<iomanip>
#include<string> 
#include<limits> 
#include<vector>

using namespace std;  

void init_matrix(int** source)
{
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            source[i][j]=count; count++;
        }
    }
}
void matrix_transpoz(int** source)
{
    int temp; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            temp = source[i][j];
            source[i][j] = source[j][i];
            source[j][i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
void print_matrix(int** source)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            cout << source[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    } 
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    int** arr; 
    int count = 1;
    arr = new int* [5]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[5];
    }

    init_matrix(arr); 
    print_matrix(arr); 
    cout << endl; 
    matrix_transpoz(arr); 
    print_matrix(arr); 
    cout << endl;
    
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Ah okay. it worked. thank you . I see that.